# How does Go keep track of pointers and update them during GC?

Tags: go

How does Go keep track of pointers and update them during GC?

According to the GoDoc, https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer

> A uintptr is an integer, not a reference. Converting a Pointer to a uintptr creates an integer value with no pointer semantics. Even if a uintptr holds the address of some object, the garbage collector will not update that uintptr's value if the object moves, nor will that uintptr keep the object from being reclaimed.

This means during GC, the go runtime can move an object to a new address and updates all pointers pointing to this object. But how does the go runtime know how many pointers are pointing to it and update them all?

In another word, how much memory does a Go pointer take? Will it take more space to save additional information to cooperate with the GC?

Comment: you should start by reading this https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote

Comment: It's undefined, and up to the implementation. The GC is not part of the language spec (and not every implementation of Go uses GC).

Comment: A go pointer is just a pointer, it doesn't contain any additional information. I think to understand how the go GC works you're going to have to read some of the articles describing its internals, and it's too much information for a stackoverflow Q/A.

Comment: "This means during GC, the go runtime can move an object to a new address" No, it doesn't . It just means that the uintptr would not  be updated if the GC would move an object. It doesn't mean that GC does move object. It doesn't. It could, but doesn't.

Comment: Why do people downvote perfectly valid and clearly stated questions?

Comment: There is a dedicated memory area for this with **2bits metadata for every word (64bits)**. From the source mentioned by @ShubhamSrivastava (thx!): *"Mark bits are kept on the side and used for marking as well as allocation. Each word has 2 bits associated with it to tell you if it was a scalar or a pointer inside that word. It also encoded whether there were more pointers in the object so we could stop scanning objects sooner than later."* https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote -- Too bad this question was closed, I find it valid and well articulated.

Answer (score 1):

> This means during GC, the go runtime can move an object to a new address and updates all pointers pointing to this object.

This kind of GC is called a *compacting collector* or *moving collector* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Moving_vs._non-moving)).

Existing Go implementations use non-moving collectors, which are generally simpler and need not address the remaining concerns you mention.  See the Wikipedia page for more about moving / compacting collectors.

The Go language per se says nothing about how the GC is to be implemented, so any time you rely on any of this, you're boxing yourself in.  Write your program such that it is agnostic to the implementation, and it will work on all Go systems; that's generally the way to go.